# Unexpected voltage from my H bridge

Tags: h-bridge

I have a problem with my H bridge. I don't understand why I have -1V insted of 12V or -12V.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe your MOSFET models are naïve. Try simulating with known good models of real transistors.

Comment: this happens when the R-on of your mosfet is too high. either it is just set to high itself (around 10k) or the turn on voltage is too large, e.g. around 12 V. does it improve when you change the supply voltage to 15 V ? or the series resistance of V2 is too big.

Comment: You've used breakout models and custom parameters for the MOSFETs. Why are you using these if you don't know how to apply them properly?

Comment: I put ".model Mbreakn NMOS LEVEL = 3(RD = 0)" but it's the same. I don't know what's a break mosfet, for me it was normal mosfet

Comment: There is a lot of real mosfet models in the pspice library, why dont you use one of those? Like IRFxxx NMOS and PMOS power FETs..

Comment: Someone have a known good models of real transistors reference ?

Comment: You could try IRF530 and IRF9530

Comment: I works very well with BSP171 P-MOS and power_mbreakn, thank you for all your help

Comment: Just a note for future reference. When making schematics for others to look at, your schematic editor almost certainly has a "mirror component" function.  In this case, use it to flip M9 and M12, so the gates are on the same side as on M10 and M11 respectively. This will get rid of confusing wire crossings. Make life easier for the ones you want to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments bellow my post, I use power mosfet and it works, I assume that it depends of internal resistance.
I use BSP171 P-MOS and power_mbreakn.